# RDP through LAN network with static IP when WiFi is on

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, remote-desktop, lan

I want to be able to connect to a closed network through LAN but to also have the WiFi open for internet.
To connect to the closed network I need to set a static IP on the Ethernet card and to have Internet through WiFi I need to leave it as automatic IP.
If I close the WiFi connection I am able to ping and RDP computers on the closed network but when WiFi is on I can't, but I do have internet connectivity.
I've tested this on a laptop with Windows 10 and on one with Windows 7 (both Pro versions) and they are both unable to do this.
Is there any way to make this work?

This is the route table with WiFi off:

```
C:\Users\{username}>route print
===========================================================================
Interface List
 13...62 f6 77 b9 d3 ef ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
 17...60 f6 77 b9 d3 f0 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
 12...a4 4c c8 6e 6b 23 ......Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (5) I219-LM
  4...60 f6 77 b9 d3 ef ......Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      11.22.33.1      11.22.33.100    291
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
       11.22.33.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      11.22.33.100    291
     11.22.33.100  255.255.255.255         On-link      11.22.33.100    291
     11.22.33.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      11.22.33.100    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      11.22.33.100    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      11.22.33.100    291
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       11.22.33.1  Default
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
 12    291 fe80::/64                On-link
 12    291 fe80::d42:ffd8:4aec:9a54/128
                                On-link
  1    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
 12    291 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

This is the route table with WiFi on:

```
C:\Users\{username}>route print
===========================================================================
Interface List
 13...62 f6 77 b9 d3 ef ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
 17...60 f6 77 b9 d3 f0 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
 12...a4 4c c8 6e 6b 23 ......Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (5) I219-LM
  4...60 f6 77 b9 d3 ef ......Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      44.55.66.1       44.55.66.66     50
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      11.22.33.1      11.22.33.100    291
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
       11.22.33.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      11.22.33.100    291
     11.22.33.100  255.255.255.255         On-link      11.22.33.100    291
     11.22.33.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      11.22.33.100    291
       44.55.66.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       44.55.66.66    306
      44.55.66.66  255.255.255.255         On-link       44.55.66.66    306
     44.55.66.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       44.55.66.66    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      11.22.33.100    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       44.55.66.66    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      11.22.33.100    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       44.55.66.66    306
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       11.22.33.1  Default
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
 12    291 fe80::/64                On-link
  4    306 fe80::/64                On-link
 12    291 fe80::d42:ffd8:4aec:9a54/128
                                    On-link
  4    306 fe80::4971:5ea9:33db:4cc7/128
                                    On-link
  1    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
 12    291 ff00::/8                 On-link
  4    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Thank you,
Liron Hallak

Comment: Show WiFi interface settings (IP-mask-gateway) and the same parameters You set to NIC interface. Show `route print` output with (no Inet) and without (Inet accessable) of setting NIC parameters. PS. I think the problem source is You try to set default gateway on the NIC interface - it's wrong, You must set route to LAN subnets only. Or maybe subnets of NIC and WiFi intersects - if so, we need **much more info** about You networks for to help You...

Comment: The problem is that when WiFi and LAN are connected I do have internet but I can't access other computers on the network.
The settings I have for the WiFi connection are all automatic, so it depends on the network I'm connecting to. I connected to my phones hotspot and to my office WiFi with no difference in the results.
The settings on LAN are without DNS, I set a static IP and gateway.

Comment: Show any WiFi connection settings and route table when this connection is on (no LAN) and off (LAN accessible). Add it to Q. text.

Comment: I can't post print screens of network settings because this is sensitive material. How do I send route prints without reviling the static ip's?

Comment: *I can't post print screens of network settings because this is sensitive material.* 1) Do not post "print screen", post console *route print* command output (copy-paste); 2) Replace real addresses with some like "11.22.33.44" keep subnetting with accuracy (if exists). Private addresses do not need in replace.

Comment: didn't see your reply until now. Sorry. I'll add the prints as you requested.

Comment: Remove default route from your LAN NIC. Add static route to the LAN subnet(s) only via LAN NIC.

Comment: What @Akina said. Have both connected but make a more direct targeted static route for the wired LAN network you want to access. Route all traffic to that given subnet (/24?). The wired interface should have no default gateway.

Comment: My LAN connection has to have a static IP and a default gateway. It's connected to a Sierra cellular router that connects me to an APN. My WiFi connection is dynamic so I receive the settings according to the network I connect to.

Comment: So the router acts as a VPN? You could still do the same, but without the default gateway. Just configure your cellular router as the next-hop for that IP-subnet in the static route. You don't need everything to traverse that VPN. If both NICs have a default GW, it will surely cause you problems.

Comment: _configure your cellular router as the next-hop for that IP-subnet in the static route_ - I have no idea how to do that. Also, if it means re configuring something in the router than I can't (not permitted). 
_If both NICs have a default GW, it will surely cause you problems_ - LAN gateway is a must because of the router, WiFi gateway is there although it's set up for automatic addressing so it comes from the network I connect to.
Am I _screwed_?

Comment: @LironHallak - You configure the static route on your client directly. In CMD, the command would look like this: route ADD <your vpn subnet> MASK <subnetmask> <gateway>. In a normal situation this could look like the following: route add 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 10.0.1.1. Set your wired NIC to a static address, and use the static route on top. This ensures you will have no gw, but will route intended traffic through the cellular VPN. Not screwed at all I would say ;)

Comment: Can you break this down for me a bit more. Right now my NIC settings have static IP 11.22.33.44, subnet 255.255.255.0 and GW 11.22.33.66. Do I need to remove just the GW? And then the command should be `route add 11.22.33.44 mask 255.255.255.0 11.22.33.66`? When I try that I get _The route addition failed: The parameter is incorrect_.

Comment: @LironHallak - You're absolutely right! Just remove the GW from the NIC settings, leaving just IP and subnet.  Also, the command is correct, as far as I can see. Try running the CMD as administrator while doing this. Also, if it kicks about wrong parameters, do a check by just typing "route"; it should give you an example of the correct syntax. I just added a route on my PC, so it should work. Mind that you need to add the "-p" flag to make the route persistent through reboots. A tip would be to add it with the -p after you have verified its working.

Comment: I managed to add the route but still couldn't RDP to the remote computer, even before I turned on the WiFi. I think I'm going to leave this issue for now. It's mainly an inconvenience and I feel I don't have enough networking knowledge to deal with this by myself. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: @LironHallak that's quite interesting then! And I fully understand. Some more time and more steps would be needed to figure it out I guess. You're welcome! If you ever want to continue this, I'll be more than happy to assist further.